# Loops and arrays in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

You can create a loop in devops pipelines YAML by using a syntax similiar to `-${{ each x in y }}:`. From my understanding, `y` can be an array.

However, I find that there is no documentation for `each`. The only page describing an example of it's usage is on [the "Templates" page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

So my question is: how do I go about specifying an array? I know one way is to use `-${{ each book in parameters.books }}:` and then pass in a "list" of `books` like:

```
- template: template.yml
  parameters: 
    books:
      - book1
      - book2
      - book3
```

However, I'd also like to define an array as a variable:

```
variables:
  books:
    - book1
    - book2
    - book3
```

However, for this, ADO throws an error `A sequence was not expected`.

Is there no way to define an array like that? I'd imagine I'd then refer to these as `-${{ each book in variables.books }}:` If not, is there any other way to specify a list?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not supported defining an array as a variable, the [variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#variables) is `variables: { string: string }`. Check the following case:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html

> Yaml variables have always been string: string mappings.
>
> We are preparing to release a feature in the near future to allow you
> to pass more complex structures. Stay tuned!

Currently, you can only use parameters to pass and loop array:

```
parameters:
- name: 'param'
  type: object
  default: 
  - FOO
  - BAR
  - ZOO

steps:
- ${{ each p in parameters.param }}:
  - script: echo ${{ p }}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I _have_ to use variables. Parameters is how I'm doing it right now, but using variables would make my pipeline much simpler.

Comment: If you can remove your parameters suggestion and add this link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html to your answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SohamDongargaonkar I have modified the answer.

Comment: the more I use MS azure I have to admit MS has come a very long way in supporting its products especially with folks like @CeceDong-MSFT who monitor and answer azure questions  ...   five stars !!!!!!!!

Comment: This works great, even inside a template called from main script, but I cannot get it to work with a list generated dynamically before being passed to the template as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387037/looping-through-variables-in-azure-pipeline/63405679#63405679 I am getting the error:  "Expected sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(VariableName)'"

Comment: this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-passing-a-variable-as-a-parameter/429990 suggests its not possible to pas a list generated at run time :-(

Comment: @leonhees posted a nice workaround, using `split()` to generate a list from a string and so allow usage of `${{each}}` over variable without the need for a template. That could be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need templates to have a for-loop. Just use the [split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split):

```yaml
- stage:
  variables:
    - name: vars
      value: dev, nonprod, production

  jobs:
  - job: print_vars
    steps:
    - ${{ each var in split(variables.vars, ', ') }}:
      - script: |
          echo ${{ var }}
        displayName: Printing ${{ var }}
```

---

You could also use the variables object itself as a map but that can lead to issues.

```yaml
- stage:
  variables:
    - name: DEV
      value: dev
    - name: NONPROD
      value: nonprod
    - name: PROD
      value: production

  jobs:
  - job: print_vars
    steps:
    - ${{ each var in variables }}:
      - script: |
          echo ${{ var.key }}
          echo ${{ var.value }}
        displayName: Printing ${{ var.key }}
```

Answer (score 10):

The way I overcame the limitations on variables arrays was to transform the variable value string into an array in the pipeline.
Parameters are not an option as they are exposed to the user at Pipeline run.

in Variables.prod.yaml:

```
variables:
- name: prod_vmnames
  value: VM1, VM2, VM3
```

in the pipeline:

```
scriptType: bash
scriptLocation: inlineScript
inlineScript: |
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - INFO  - Script started"
  
  # "Generating Prod VMs array"
  IFS="," read -a vms_array <<< ${{ variables.prod_vmnames }}
  echo "VMs array is: $vms_array"

  # Run script on all VMs
  chmod +x AzVmRun.sh
  for vm in ${vms_array[@]}
  do
    echo "Launching script /Scripts/AzVmRun.sh on vm: $vm"
    ./AzVmRun.sh \
      -v $vm -k ${{ variables.kvname }}
  done
```

HTH.

Comment: Alas, that means the inner loop is shell script - which is completely different than a series of YAML steps.... [completely different skill set for yriting YAML, knowing tasks and parameters than from knowing Linus for modifying AzVmRun.sh".