# Looping through variables in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I have a text file with two names in it `client1` and `client2`.

I have a Powershell script made to read the text file and my understanding of it is that it creates an array already.

```
$clientvariable = Get-Content -Path {FilePath}/{File};
Write-Host "vso[task.setvariable variable=clientname]$clientvariable
```

So now clientname has the value $clientvariable which is set to `client1 client2` and I can index each position if needed.

How can I use this in an Azure pipeline YAML so that each name can be individually looked at and looped through one after the next?

The goal is to take each name and create a resource with the name from the file in conjuction with an ARM template i.e. `client1SQLserver` `client2SQLserver`

I've seen that you can use templates with parameteres to create for loops so would that work in this case or is there some other way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Note: you can't loop through an array variable in the pipeline; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530649/174843

Answer (score 4):

> How can I use this in an Azure pipeline YAML so that each name can be individually looked at and looped through one after the next?

We could specify that a job run based on the value of an output variable set in a previous job to loop each name individually.

Since I do not have text file name, I use the custom character array instead of file names in my sample, like `$FileNames = '"test1","test2","test3","test4"'`:

My Azure pipeline yaml file:

```
trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - master


    stages:
      - stage: LoopFileName
        jobs:
        - job: A
          pool:
            name: MyPrivateAgent
          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            condition: succeeded()
            displayName: "Create a list"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                  $FileNames = '"test1","test2","test3","test4"'
                      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LoopFileName;isOutput=true]$FileNames"                
            name: fileoutput
    
        - job: B
          dependsOn: A
          pool:
            name: MyPrivateAgent
          variables: 
            AllFileNames: $[dependencies.A.outputs['fileoutput.LoopFileName']]
          steps:
          - template: loopTemplate.yml
            parameters: 
              files : $(AllFileNames)
```

Then the `loopTemplate.yml` file:

```
parameters:
  files: []

steps :
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Fetching ValueFiles'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: >

      foreach ($i in ${{parameters.files}})
      {
        Write-Host "filenames=$i"
      }
```

The test result:

[image]

In this case, we could create a resource with the name.

You could check the document [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help Leo, I will look into this tomorrow or Saturday and get back to you. At the moment in my ARM deployment I use the overrideParameters field since I am able to get my variable equal to just a single name. Will it still be possible to pass in this new variable and have the ARM template still work? I assume I would need to do something such as ```-parameter $(i)``` if I understood your code.

Comment: Also wanted to ask, in your pipeline YAML do you need to define $FileNames as you did or can you have your script read a document and create that list? My code for how I was pulling in names is in the OP I am just not sure if the way my script was pulling in names was in a similar format to your naming convention for $FileNames.

Comment: @ubiquitinoob44, I think we could create script read a document and create that list with powershell scripts. But since I am not an expert in powershell, I cannot give such a sample directly, personally think it is feasible. I will try to find a sample about it and share it with you later.

Comment: @ubiquitinoob44, Found it! Check the PowerShell task in the azure-pipeline.yaml file in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425275/how-to-use-output-of-a-powershell-command-as-parameters-in-azure-pipeline. `Write-Host "Fetching value files"
       cd myfolder
       $a=git ls-files
       $List = $a | foreach {'**/myfolder/dev/' + $_}
       Write-Host $List
       $d = '"{0}"' -f ($List -join '","')
       ...`

Comment: @ubiquitinoob44, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: This is a great answer, but is it possible to use the parameter in an each loop?  i.e. `steps:
  - ${{ each p in parameters.files}}:
      - script: echo ${{ p}}`
when I try I get error "Expected sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(AllFileNames)'"

Comment: in response to myself, it appears that the generation of the list as a variable and passing as a parameter is limited to having to cross a job boundary as the parameter expression expansion happens before the run (of the job).  My scenario requires files generated during the first job to be available during the second, I think a redesign of the flow is required...

for info

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-passing-a-variable-as-a-parameter/429990